# How to save and retrieve drupal ckeditor media in cdn

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-modules, cdn

I am using ckeditor, I need to upload and retrieve the media used in ckeditor from CDN .Currently it is saving it in the base path (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/ ). I want it to save and retrive from my CDN.

I did found [uploadcare](http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadcare) but i didn`t understand how to use this and also i think it has its own cdn where as i am trying to find a way to save it in my own cdn.

Thanks for help

**Similar question :**

[define-ckeditor-add-media-library-location](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95005/define-ckeditor-add-media-library-location)

[how-to-save-ckeditor-wysiwug-media-in-cdn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105078/how-to-save-ckeditor-wysiwug-media-in-cdn)

Answer (score 1):

[Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) indeed uses it's own CDN in case of CKEditor integration.

Most CDN providers will allow you to set base URL of content that you want to be available via CDN (e.g. http://www.example.com/uploads/images/). So that http://some-cdn.com/image.jpeg will distribute your image uploaded by ckeditor to http://www.example.com/uploads/images/image.jpeg

This is the easiest way to configure "PULL" CDN.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. You can if you with set your CDN in front of Uploadcare's CDN, but this is somewhat pointless. You can contact Uploadcare directly about the service at hello@uploadcare.com